# Filter out older devices using manifest

Tags: android, google-play, device-compatibility

I'm developing an app that's intended for high-end devices only. It already only supports API 17+ but I've noticed some older devices that run API 17 that I'd like to exclude. My question is:

**What's the best way to filter out older devices that still run a relatively new Android version?**

I'd like to avoid manually excluding specific devices in Google Play.

**Filtering based on screen density** 
One thing that I'd certainly like to do is filter on screen density (I'd like to support only hdpi and higher). I've read the [compatible-screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html) article but I don't really like the solution presented there because:

1. According to the article: "You should use it only as a last resort, when the application absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations."
2. I'll get a large list of combinations in my manifest (if I support hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi with screen sizes medium, large and xlarge I'll already have 12 combinations).
3. What if a new screen density (e.g. xxxxhdpi) or a new screen size (e.g. xxlarge) is added? To support those I'd have to update my manifest every time a new bucket is added.

It seems strange to me that I can't just specify that I want to support hdpi and higher in a single line in the manifest.

**Filtering based on device features** 
I've also considered filtering on some feature that only high-end devices have, so I read the [uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) article. However, it seems that I can only filter on things like bluetooth, camera and wi-fi and not on anything more indicative of a high-end device like hardware acceleration.

Comment: Android has a whole spectrum of devices ranging from very old or low quality, to very powerful and large, there's no clear definition of a device being high/low-end. can you explain your reasons to exclude lower-end devices? Maybe there's a better way to solve what you're trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

You just can't filter out specific device(s) using the **AndroidManifest.xml** file itself except the **screen size/density** etc. say if you need to filter out a specific handset/tablet for a specific vendor then is will not be possible using the manifest file only.

> **"What is the best way to filter out older devices that still run a relatively new Android version?"**

**Solution:** There are options in [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) by which you can filter specific devices (handsets/tablets/models etc) according to vendor and model number for a particular app you have published.

To do this goto the **APK** section of your app:

[image]

Now click either on **See List** or **Manage excluded devices** the usage is very easy and self explanatory. This show show something like this:

[image]

Now All you need to do is just click on the [image] button and it will be added to the **Excluded Devices**.

Hope it helps `:)`

Comment: `I'd like to avoid manually excluding specific devices in Google Play.`